# Trigger HTTP POST request on remote URL when logged into current URL

Tags: php, jquery, single-sign-on

I've a web app written in CodeIgniter (PHP) hosted on `domain-a.com`. There is another app on hosted on other server under domain `domain-b.com` that acts as SSO (Single Sign On) for multiple apps. I need to integrate that SSO for a limited period.

My use case is, when a user login to my app at `domain-a.com`, he should also get logged into the IDP (Identitiy Provider) of SSO at `domain-b.com`. I've tried to iFrame the SSO page at `domain-b.php` in the login page of my app at `domain-a.com` and create a login button click event on the iFramed page with the form filled-in with the data from the form that user enter in my app's login form at `domain-a.com`. That didn't seem to work as I was unable to create events on iFramed webpage.

Any suggestions on how can this be achieved is appreciated.

P.S: I have edit access to both websites and can change backend PHP and front end files.

Comment: On your login data handling page for `domain-a.com`, after checking the credentials are ok, you can then [send the POST data](https://viniciusmuniz.com/en/send-post-request-without-form/) to the login handling page of `domain-b.com`. Add a token that says it was sent from domain-a, and handle it accordingly

Comment: @tola - Looks like its not that easy nowadays. There is CSRF implementation everywhere. I was unable to POST like u suggested, so I tried iFrame-ing which didn't work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried the postMessage something like below and it worked for me using iFrame. Hopefully, someone can find this useful.

on domain-a.com,

```
<iframe src="https://domain-b.com" id="ssoapp" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<script>
const SSOProvider = "https://domain-b.com";
let reqData = {
    "username": $('#username').val(),
    "password": $('#password').val(),
};
var ssoapp = document.getElementById('ssoapp');
ssoapp.contentWindow
    .postMessage(
        JSON.stringify(reqData),
        SSOProvider
    );
</script>
```

on domain-b.com,

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', handleRequest, false);

function handleRequest(e) {

    if (e.origin === 'https://domain-a.com') {
        
        let requestData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        
        document.getElementById('username').value = requestData.username;
        document.getElementById('password').value = requestData.password;
        document.getElementById('submit_button').click();
        
    }

}
</script>
```